# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'. Whats wrong in my SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    itemid, itemcategory.descrption as brand, itemcode, costprice, 
    qoh as whqty, gender, ia.type, display, dialcolor, strapcolor, 
    clasp, ia.case, bracelet, caseback, casedia, ia.function, 
    hand, glass, face, lug, length, waterresistant, movement, 
    movcountry, weight, warranty, box, manual 
from 
    masterdata_retail.dbo.item i 
left join
    masterdata_retail.dbo.itemcategory description ic on i.itemid = ic.itemid  
left join 
    masterdata_retail.dbo.itemstock is on i.itemid = is.itemid 
left join
    masterdata_retail.dbo.itemattribute ia on i.itemid = ia.itemid 
where 
    is.outletid = 1 
    and itemcode in ('VP46J025Y')
```

Comment: `CASE` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It's a bad idea to use such names as the name of a column since then you need to quote the name.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: and so is `function`  ..

Comment: I added quotations on case, function, length, weight, manual. now the error is this:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'itemid'.

Comment: And what do you think that new error message is telling you? And why do you expect we, who have no access to your table definitions, will be able to do a better job of finding the right column name than you will?

Comment: Yes, found the error now. Thanks :")

Answer (score 0):

```
select itemid, itemcategory.descrption as brand, itemcode, costprice, 
qoh as whqty, gender, ia.type, display, dialcolor, strapcolor, 
clasp, ia.[case], bracelet, caseback, casedia, ia.[function], hand, glass, 
face, lug, length, waterresistant, movement, movcountry, weight, warranty, box, 
manual 
from masterdata_retail.dbo.item i 
left join masterdata_retail.dbo.[itemcategory description] ic on i.itemid = ic.itemid 
left join masterdata_retail.dbo.itemstock [is] on i.itemid = [is].itemid 
left join masterdata_retail.dbo.itemattribute ia on i.itemid = ia.itemid where [is].outletid = 1 and itemcode in('VP46J025Y')
```

Comment: Explanation: to use reserved words as column names they have to be quoted

Comment: select i.itemid, ic.description as brand, itemcode, costprice, qoh as whqty, 
gender, ia.type, display, dialcolor, strapcolor, clasp, [case], bracelet, caseback, casedia, [function], hand, glass, face, 
lug, [length], waterresistant, movement, movcountry, [weight], warranty, box, [manual] 
from masterdata_retail.dbo.item i left join masterdata_retail.dbo.itemcategory ic on i.itemid = ic.itemid 
left join masterdata_retail.dbo.itemstock istock on i.itemid = istock.itemid 
left join masterdata_retail.dbo.itemattribute ia on i.itemid = ia.itemid

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'itemid'.

Comment: one of the tables in the join clauses does not have an itemid column. check  the itemcategory table, most likely you would want to join on a column categoryid or something similar

Comment: Yes found it and fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Code-only answers do not teach. At the very least you should at least identify what you changed.